# How to parameterize coefficient matrix to restrict eigenvalues?

Tags: time-series, optimization, parameterization

Consider the $r-$dimensional autoregression

$$
y_t = Ay_{t-1} + v_t, v_t \overset{iid}{\sim}N(0,\Sigma).
$$

It is well known that if all eigenvalues of $A$ have modulus less than unity then this process has a stationary distribution. If $r = 1$ one could reparameterize the model by setting, e.g., $A = \pi^{-1}2\arctan\theta_1, \Sigma = \exp(\theta_2)$ and have the process be stationary and well defined for every $\theta = [\theta_1, \theta_2]' \in \mathbb R^2$.

**Question:** Is there a similar reparameterization for $r>1$?

*I am primarily interested in how to parameterize $A$ in a way that lends itself well to unconstrained optimization and ensures all eigenvalues have modulus less than unity.* If the $\arctan(\cdot)$ transformation suggested for the $r=1$ case is bad from an optimization perspective I would also like to know that.

I know there is a fair bit of work on how to parameterize $\Sigma$ so that is not a problem.